# MKMapView memory usage steadily increasing

Tags: memory, mkmapview, automatic-ref-counting, mapkit

In my app, I've noticed that as I push and pop a view controller containing an `MKMapView`, memory usage steadily increases. I've determined that there is a problem with MapKit itself, not my code, though. I made a test project containing simply a navigation controller in which I repeatedly can push and pop a view controller containing nothing but a map view- no annotations or overlays. As I push and pop the view controller over and over, memory usage increases by about .6 MB each push/pop cycle. Any thoughts as to why this is happening? I am using ARC. Thanks!

**Edit:**

I've done some testing in the iOS 5.1 simulator (I'm aware of the issues regarding profiling in the simulator, but I don't have any iOS 5 devices available for testing), and my results indicate that this is a bug in iOS 6; in the iOS 6 simulator I see the gradual increase in memory usage, but in the iOS 5 simulator, memory usage doesn't rise. I suppose this is an issue with Apple's new in-house maps.

Comment: Does it get reclaimed when you force a memory warning? Are there leaks happening? Do some more profiling using instruments I'd say. Then file a radar if you've isolated a concrete bug.

Comment: Some memory is reclaimed when I force a memory warning (~40% of the total lost memory) and Instruments is not reporting any leaks (which is expected since I'm using ARC).

Comment: ARC does not mean there cannot be leaks.

Comment: It does mean that I have less control over them

Comment: You're less likely to have leaks, yes. What I mean is though, there could still be leaks in MapKit. Although unlikely one appearing for the simple case you've described.

Comment: I've edited my question with more information.

Comment: Make sure to file a rdar: https://bugreport.apple.com