# MKMapView and memory management in iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller, mkmapview, instruments

I have a `MKMapView` managed in certain `UIViewController`. This view controller is pushed/popped from a `UINavigationController`. When running the app with Xcode's Intruments to see the memory allocations and look for leaks, I find that, starting from a certain `Live Bytes` value, when I navigate to such view controller with a map view, and then I navigate back, the view controller is deallocated but the `Live Bytes` value I had before navigating forth is always incremented more or less the same amount of bytes.

I've navigated forth and back from the view controller with the map several times in a row to show you the values: the screenshots were taken once navigated back from the view controller.

[image: first time back]

[image: second time back]

[image: third time back]

I "nilify" all view controller's views and subviews in `viewDidUnload` delegate method, and I also "nilify" strong properties and remove map's annotations and overlays in `viewWillDisappear:`. What could be causing that increment in `Live Bytes` every time I navigate back from this view controller? Is it because of the map view itself?

The screenshots are from a device running iOS 6.1

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** the leaks graph in Instruments is "clean":

[image: leaks]

**EDIT 2:** I've tested the same scenario in a device running iOS 7.1 and I don't see the increment in `Live Bytes` when navigating back. It seems to be an issue related to iOS 6, and I found some posts dealing with it:

[How to resolve the memory issue with Map on iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280106/how-to-resolve-the-memory-issue-with-map-on-ios-6)

[MKMapView memory usage steadily increasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904990/mkmapview-memory-usage-steadily-increasing)

However, I don't find a solution, is it actually an iOS 6.X bug?

**EDIT 3:** I tried the following solutions, but still get the same values in Instruments:

- [Memory not being released for MKMapView w/ ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420018/memory-not-being-released-for-mkmapview-w-arc)
- [How to clear the cache of mkmapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553085/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-mkmapview)

I don't get any memory warning, though.

Comment: ... and what did the leaks tool tell you? Not your own guesswork based on one metric in isolation, the actual tool?

Comment: @Tommy the leaks graph does not show any peak...

Comment: Living bytes = the number of objects created and still residing on the heap. So top options are: (i) `MKMapView`s caching adds up, and isn't obliged to work how you or I would guess; and, less likely (ii) the relevant objects aren't actually leaked — there's a reference somewhere to something deep that you're missing. But that'd normally be from some manual view manipulation that doesn't work correctly or adding something to a more-global data store and forgetting to remove it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS6 MKMapView using a ton of memory, to the point of crashing the app, anyone else notice this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641658/ios6-mkmapview-using-a-ton-of-memory-to-the-point-of-crashing-the-app-anyone-e)

Comment: @Thedude not exactly, I think... this post complains about the memory usage while using the map view. The issue I find is the memory increment when the map view is not shown anymore...

Comment: Sorry, my fault, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420018/memory-not-being-released-for-mkmapview-w-arc

Comment: @Thedude Thanks. I tried that solution and it doesn't work for me...

Comment: Did you find an answer? Still an issue in iOS 9. Segue to and from a map view eventually crashes due to memory warning.